# Backslash followed by a lowercase alphabet in javascript string is breaking the string

Tags: javascript, string, javascript-objects, innerhtml

WRT following javscript code1 assigns a single string to innerhTML but Code2 separates the string i.e. it terminates the string as soon as it encounters a "\" (backslsh) followed by a **lowercase** letter. But if i replace it by a upper case letter or add 2 \ it works fine.

> I've a sitiation where i can't alter the string: "root\uMBUS", BUT I
>   CAN DO SOME JAVASCRIPT THINGY TO MAKE SURE THE STRING IS ASSIGNED AS A
>   SINGLE STRING TO INNERHTML.

**Code1:**

```
function ABC() {  document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML ='<th>"root\UMBUS"</th>';}  
// Works fine 'coz \ is followed by a uppercase alphabet.
```

**Code 2:**

```
function ABC2() {  document.getElementById('abc2').innerHTML ='<th>"root\uMBUS"</th>';}
    // String breaks 'coz \ is followed by a lowercase alphabet.
```

Comment: The backslash is an escape character and needs to be escaped in every string! Use `"root\\UMBUS"`

Comment: Why do you think you cannot alter the string?

Comment: @Bergi: It woks fine when i use a uppercase character next to a \ (backslash). BUt the problem is when i use a lowercase character.

Comment: No, it doesn't work fine. It's an invalid escape sequence, and the single backslash is simply ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your JavaScript engine is interpreting `\uMBUS` as a Unicode sequence.  On top of this, `\uMBUS` is not a valid Unicode sequence.  To prevent this from happening, you could try escaping the backslash:

```
function ABC2() {  document.getElementById('abc2').innerHTML ='<th>"root\\uMBUS"</th>';}
                                                                        ^^ escape \\u here
```

By using a literal backslash, the sequence `\uMBUS` should also be interpreted as being literal.

To confirm what I am claiming just try the following code snippet on any JS engine:

```
var stuff = '\u2700';
```

If you inspect `stuff`, you should see a scissors dingbat character.  Then try the following, and observe the error message that you get:

```
var stuff = '\uMBUS';
```

Comment: Yes, i know it works with another\ but if it needs adding another \ (backslash) , but how does this work when i use a uppercase character next to \ (backslash).

Comment: @codeLover Because Unicode sequences begin with `\u` not `\U`, check here: http://rextester.com/RKWWC35118

Comment: Thank you.Without modifying the string is there any way (in JS) to correct this ?

Comment: Probably the best way to handle this would be to control/stop the insertion of Unicode characters into your literal text.  Fix it at the source, and then you avoid having to do JavaScript olympics to fix it.